# Spring Committing Before Transaction Exits

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-transactions, autocommit

We're trying to upgrade from Spring 2.5.2 to 4.0.5.RELEASE, but have discovered that Spring's transactional management no longer functions.

In our production app, all database operations go through a Spring bean marked with the @Transactional annotation (with default settings). For several years, this has worked as expected, with rollbacks occurring if a RuntimeException is thrown inside the transaction boundaries. However, when we upgrade to Spring 4.0.5.RELEASE, it acts as autocommit is set to true.

We verified that the problem code is still running inside the transaction proxy, by looking at the stack trace. But when we execute a simple one row update to a table just after entering the transaction, the update is **committed**.  This puzzling, since all we did is change the Spring version.

Did the auto commit behavior change in later Spring versions? Is there some additional configuration we need to do under 4.05?

---

Here's the configuration for our transaction manager (same in both 2.52 & 4.05 versions):

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="efmsDataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="efmsDataSource" class="com.uprr.eni.commons.dao.OracleDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@${db_instance}.oracle.uprr.com:1521:${db_instance}" />
    <property name="username" value="${db_user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${db_password}" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="8" />
</bean>
```

Here's the bean which has a @Transactional method in our code:

```
<bean id="efmsExecutor" class="com.uprr.eni.commons.dao.exec.DataSourceExecutorBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="efmsDataSource" />
</bean>
```

Here's how we create application context & get the transational bean, then save it as a static variable:

```
context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(CONFIG_FILES);
efmsExecutorBean = (DataSourceExecutorBean)context.getBean(EFMS_EXECUTOR_BEAN);
```

We save that bean in a static variable & refer to it when we to execute a transaction. Should we be doing something differently?

---

When we want to start a transaction, we call:

```
efmsExecutorBean.executeTransaction(executor);
```

This is the method we call in DataSourceExecutorBean to kick off a transaction. It basically just passes its internal data source to the executor (the code the that will actually do the database work).

```
@Transactional public void executeTransaction(final DataSourceExecutor executor) {

    executor.execute(source);                                   // Perform the unit of work
    final StringList errors = executor.getResult().getErrors(); // Did any errors occur?
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {                                    // If so
        for (final String error : errors) {
            ApiLog.error(error);                                // Record them
        }
        throw new ExecutorError(ERROR, executor.getName());     // Abort
    }
}
```

---

As I was re-checking the logs for the two versions, I notice that the 4.0.5 (broken) version has some entries that the 2.5.2 version does **not** have. These entries appear just as the transaction starts:

> **2014-07-31 09:34:43,576 [btpool0-0] DEBUG - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'efmsDataSource' 2014-07-31 09:34:43,576 [btpool0-0]
>   DEBUG - Creating instance of bean 'efmsDataSource' 2014-07-31
>   09:34:43,576 [btpool0-0] DEBUG - Eagerly caching bean 'efmsDataSource'
>   to allow for resolving potential circular references**

Perhaps this explains what's happening (but not why). It looks like **the singleton data source bean isn't really a singleton**. Google shows a few people with a similar problem, but no indication of how to solve it.  Does this ring bells with anyone?

Comment: It seems that the transactions have the same behavior, reading the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html). Can you put the configurations of transaction manager?

Comment: There's no additional configuration or known breakage of the transaction support. Did you only change the Spring version or other changes were made as well? Can you show the code?

Comment: New Info: After tracing thru the Spring code, we found a difference in behavior between the two versions. In the broken (4.0.5) version, Spring is getting a creating a new transaction manager & new data source from the application context. So, when it sets autocommit to false, it sets on a **different connection** than our code is using.

Answer (score 0):

Does your code use the Oracle datasource directly (rather than through e.g. JdbcTemplate?) If so, you need to wrap it in a TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy and inject that into your data access beans.

Comment: Finally found the cause: During initialization, our app was calling ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.close() after extracting the beans. This close() call was put in place several years ago when Eclipse issued a warning about potential resource leak because the context **wasn't** closed. Calling close() was harmless in Spring 2.5.2, but not in later versions. Sadly, to this day, the Spring Javadocs don't warn about the potentially disastrous consequences of calling context.close(). Thanks for taking the time to read our wordy post!